# bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb and error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am using Michael Hartl's ruby on rail tutorial.

When I try to execute the command:`bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb`

I get the following errors:

```
mudit@Bat:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/values/time_zone.rb:268: warning: circular argument reference - now
        SECURITY WARNING: No secret option provided to Rack::Session::Cookie.
        This poses a security threat. It is strongly recommended that you
        provide a secret to prevent exploits that may be possible from crafted
        cookies. This will not be supported in future versions of Rack, and
        future versions will even invalidate your existing user cookies.

        Called from: /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/abstract_store.rb:28:in `initialize'.
Rack::File headers parameter replaces cache_control after Rack 1.5.
/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <module:FixtureSupport>': private method `fixture_path' called for #<RSpec::Core::Configuration:0x000000017db6e8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  fixture_path=
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:17:in `class_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/fixture_support.rb:17:in `block in <module:FixtureSupport>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/concern.rb:119:in `class_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/concern.rb:119:in `append_features'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:791:in `include'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:791:in `safe_include'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:785:in `block in configure_group'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:783:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:783:in `configure_group'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/world.rb:47:in `configure_group'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:290:in `set_it_up'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:241:in `subclass'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:228:in `describe'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:18:in `describe'
    from /home/mudit/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

My static_pages_spec.rb is as follows:

```
  require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
      visit '/static_pages/home'
      expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end
  end
end
```

My spec_helper.rb is as follows:

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"


  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"
  config.include Capybara::DSL

end
```

My Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

group :development, :test do

    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
end

group :test do
    gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
    gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
end 

gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.4'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'




group :production do

    gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try comment this line

```
config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
```

You may see here
https://github.com/intridea/rails_wizard.web/issues/39
http://procbits.com/2011/08/18/using-mongoid-with-rspec